# Sorting rows by children?

Tags: postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data    TEXT,
  parent  INT,
  posted  INT
);
```

Each item has a piece of data, a timestamp, and a parent. I'd like to select the top 10 root items (parent = 0), sorted by the timestamp of the most recent child.

If item #1 has a child #2 that has a child #3, #3 is considered a child of #1.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are we to assume that there is an implicit foreign key `parent` -> `id` here? If not, where does the parent/child relationship come from? (It'd help if you supplied sample data via http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Which is the timestamp column?

Comment: `If item #1 has a child #2 that has a child #3, #3 is considered a child of #1.` If all children and grandchildren are considered to be children of root items, then basically, you want to select all items that are not root items and then sort them in the reverse chronological order, right? Something like `SELECT * FROM items WHERE parent <> 0 ORDER BY <timestamp column> DESC LIMIT 10;`

Comment: @JosephB Yes, but I want to be able to limit the number of root items, and thus limit the number of children items accordingly. Also, timestamp column is `posted`.

Comment: @Brandon Thank you for the clarification. Please see answer below. You can remove the `where parent <> 0` condition if you want to select the parents as well. You would note that the seeds CTE is located second (after the get_children CTE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:

The query has been rewritten to

1. first sort the child items
2. get the root parent id and the rank for each item
3. select the top 10 parents
4. select the details for the top 10 parents

Common Table expressions have been used to incrementally select the data following the above steps.

```
WITH recursive c AS
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM seeds
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      T.id,
      T.parent,
      c.topParentID,
      (c.child_level + 1),
      c.child_rank
    FROM items AS T
    INNER JOIN c ON T.parent = c.id
    WHERE T.id <> T.parent
  )
, seeds AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    parent,
    parent AS topParentID,
    0      AS child_level,
    rank() OVER (ORDER BY posted DESC) child_rank
  FROM items
  WHERE parent <> 0
  ORDER BY posted DESC
)
, rank_level AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    c2.id id,
    c_ranks.min_child_rank child_rank,
    c_roots.max_child_level root_level
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        id,
        MAX(child_level) max_child_level
      FROM c
      GROUP BY id
    )
    c_roots
  INNER JOIN c c2 ON c_roots.id = c2.id
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        id,
        MIN(child_rank) min_child_rank
      FROM c
      GROUP BY id
    )
    c_ranks
  ON c2.id = c_ranks.id
)
, top_10_parents AS
(
  SELECT
    c.topParentID id,
    MIN(rl.child_rank) id_rank
  FROM rank_level rl
  INNER JOIN c ON rl.id = c.id AND c.child_level = rl.root_level
  GROUP BY c.topParentID
  ORDER BY MIN(rl.child_rank) 
  limit 10
)
SELECT
  i.*
FROM
  items i
INNER JOIN top_10_parents tp ON tp.id = i.id
ORDER BY tp.id_rank;
```

[<kbd>SQL Fiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/94e8a/24)

**Reference**:

[WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions) on PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: Works flawlessly. Cheers. Thanks for showing me `WITH RECURSIVE`.

Comment: Wait, I notice this sorts by the parent's timestamp. How can I sort by the latest child's timestamp of each parent?

Comment: @Brandon I rewrote the query to sort by the child's timestamp. Please check the revised answer above and the updated SQL Fiddle.